# How can I query all documents from a MongoDB database faster from AWS Lambda?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and MongoDB. I have website API which uses the `aws-sdk` node module in Node.js to call an AWS Lambda function. The website API is tied to a Lambda@Edge function within CloudFront (using `serverless-nextjs`). The Lambda function connects to a MongoDB database and queries all the documents from it. There are about 6000 documents with a total size of about 500 mb. Right now, each time I query all the documents, it takes more than 30 seconds and I get a timeout error (max timeout is 30 seconds for Lambda@Edge). The amount of documents in my database will increase rapidly overtime. I was wondering how I can query the MongoDB documents faster.

My use case:

The user picks from a set of options from the website. The website API then calls the Lambda function and passes the user preferences. The Lambda function first queries all documents in the database and then assigns a score to each document on how similar it is to the user's preferences. It then sorts the array of documents in descending order based on score and returns it.

I am essentially ranking the documents based on user preferences (Multiple Criteria Decision Analysis, MCDA) and display the results from best to worst score.

Comment: Can you setup any cache between lambda and MongoDB?

Comment: Do you mean caching the documents on the website server i.e. in a S3 bucket?

Comment: As far as I can tell you only have two options: find a way not to query all the documents if possible (just fetch the one you are interested in) or don't do it at all. If the number increases consistently no amount of performance improvements will help you given enough time. So to me it seems your architecture needs a re-think. Unfortunately, without more information it is hard to tell if you can implement your requirement any other way.

Comment: @Jens Well for my use case, the user picks from a set of options from the website. The website API then calls the Lambda function and passes the user preferences. The Lambda function first queries all documents in the database and then assigns a score to each document on how similar it is to the user's preferences. It then sorts the array of documents in descending order based on score and returns it.

Comment: @Jacnial You need to change your approach. Even if your query is super fast, if you have millions of documents the time to return them will be too big. If you really want to do this, you need to find a way to find the top 10/20/30 documents in short time and return them. For example: pre-compute the top items for the selected options. For example: if user selects option A,D and K, then return those 10 documents. If this is pre-computed it should be fast to fetch from a proper database and since you only return a fixed number of documents, it should "scale". Or use pagination.

Comment: Look into ```indexes``` provided by mongoDB that allow you to run efficient execution of queries and avoid scanning whole documents, but if you require a whole document, this may not save you but get you to a better solution.

Comment: @Jens I forgot to mention that I am not returning all the documents with each of their fields. I am only returning the documents with their assigned `id` field and so the data I am sending to the website is greatly reduced. On the website, I cache the document ids and have pagination setup for the results. On each page, I query the specific ids (e.g. the first 10 ids for the first page) to the MongoDB database and the get full documents to display the results. The problem is on the Lambda function. Each document's score depends on the maximum of a specific field...

Comment: ...in the current set of documents. And so, I cannot pre-compute the score when I create the document because I would have to change it if more documents are added (since the maximum of the specific field can change). If I could pre-compute the score, I would just query all document but just with a `score` field and thus not having to query 500 mb of data over the internet.

Comment: @MargachChris Well my query is essentially `find({})`.

Comment: @Jacnial Have you looked into the bucket pattern, it tries to solve such a problem but that means you would have to change your document structure.

Comment: @MargachChris Nope I haven't but I'll look into now, thanks.